# What are the uses of SetWriteDeadline

Tags: networking, go, connection

Can someone please give me a few scenarios where I might use [SetWriteDeadline](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPConn.SetWriteDeadline)? I know that [SetReadDeadline](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPConn.SetReadDeadline) helps a developer to determine whether the connected endpoint is still reachable or not (with the help of PING/PONG frames), but I can't figure out why I might use SetWriteDeadline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Write to a connection](https://godoc.org/net#Conn.Write) returns an error when the write operation does not complete by [the last set deadline](https://godoc.org/net#Conn.SetWriteDeadline).

The typical use of a write deadline is to detect a peer that is not reading data or is not reading data at an acceptable rate.

A robust application will set both read and write deadlines (but usually not to the same value).

Comment: Is it okay to say that the value of the SetWriteDeadline should be the same as the frequency at which the application is sending a PING FRAME (in terms of ws protocol)?

Comment: The write deadline specifies when you expect write operation to complete. This time is unrelated to the how often the application sends a ping.

Comment: Understood. Well Mr.Kake, thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

> A robust application will set both read and write deadlines

But preferable with Go 1.12 (Q1 2019).
See [golang/go issue 25729](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25729): `net: SetDeadline` performance is poor

That has recently been fixed:

> Both the improvements in throughput and latency are far less affected by -cpu values. Nice job!